# Cows and bulls game that keeps on sayin 0 cows, 0 bulls?

Tags: python

I am making a cows and bulls game, where you are supposed to guess a four digit number. The computer keeps on saying 0 cows, 0 bulls when I run the program and I dont know why or how to fix it

```
import random
print("Welcome to the cows and bulls game!") 

number = [random.randint(0,9), random.randint(0,9), random.randint(0,9), random.randint(0,9)] counter = 0 teller1 = 0 teller2 = 0

while True : 

    guess = input("Enter a four digit number:")
    bulls= 0
    cows = 0

    if cows == 4:
        print("Congratulations, you have won the game. you only used:", counter, " attempts")
        break

    for i in range(4):
        if guess[teller1] == number[teller2]:
            cows = cows + 1
            teller1 = teller1 + 1
            teller2 = teller2 + 1

    teller1 = 0

    for i in range(4):
        teller2 = teller1 - 1
        for i in range(3):
            if guess[teller1] == number[teller2]:
                bulls = bulls + 1
                teller1 = teller1 + 1

    print(cows," cows, ", bulls," bulls")

    counter = counter + 1
```

There are no error messages, but it keeps on saying 0 cows, 0 bulls.

Comment: Are you sure this is the python script and it has no errors? Where is the colon after the while true? In python, inddnting is critical, where is thd indenting for thd body of your while loop? You initialise teller1 and 2 to zero outside of your loop. It would probably be better to reset them to 0 each time you input a guess (i.e. inside the loop)

Comment: yeah, when i was formatting the script to become a code on this site, some things went here and there and the syntax might be a little bad...

Comment: Please test your code before posting it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `number` variable is a list of `int`, but your `guess` variable is a string. So when you do `if guess[teller1] == number[teller2]`, you are comparing integers to strings, which is always false.

You can fix it by converting your string to a list of integers:

```py
guess = [int(num) for num in input("Enter a four digit number:")]
```

Note that a proper solution would also validate the input given by the user (what happens if they type "12345"? "hello world"? nothing?).